# Panel within another Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I have 2 panels. Each start at the same location.(Let's say 10,10) and have the same size.

I have 2 buttons.  One shows the first panel and the other shows the second panel.

**My code is:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Visible = true;
            panel2.Visible = false;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Visible = false;
            panel2.Visible = true;
        }
```

When I press button one the the first panel shows up, but when click button 2 the second panel doesn't show up. The panel's visible properties are initially false..

What is wrong?

Comment: Double check you wired up the button2_Click event

Comment: control  in Form1.Designer if there is button2_Click event

Comment: @Alex I checked, it's wired up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that Panel2 is not a child window of Panel1.

Comment: Right, he answered his question in his title. If panel2 is a child of panel1 it will never be visible, because when panel1 is set invisible, all its children get invisible, too.

Comment: Looks like I missed a comment - Hinek is correct. If you dropped Panel2 on Panel1, then Panel2 will be a child of Panel1 and so will not be visible if Panel1 is invisible. Drop both panels onto the _form_, and then set their Location property using the property editor rather than using drag-drop. This avoids the designer thinking you meant to drop one panel _into_ the other.

Comment: @Neil Moss I'm gonna try and let you know what you said.

Comment: Also, the "Document Outline" window can be used to control the parent child relationship of controls.  See "View" - "Other Windows" - "Document Outline" when in design mode.

Comment: @Un_NatMenDim - you're welcome. I'd be grateful if you would please mark this post as the answer to the question.